# Why doesn't this code find any duplicates within an xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StateSeparationRequestCollection xsi:schemaLocation="https://uidataexchange.org/schemas SeparationRequest.xsd" xmlns="https://uidataexchange.org/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <StateSeparationRequest>
    <StateRequestRecordGUID>30000000000000000000000000004000</StateRequestRecordGUID>
        <SSN>999999999</SSN>
    </StateSeparationRequest>
    <StateSeparationRequest>
    <StateRequestRecordGUID>30000000000000000000000000004000</StateRequestRecordGUID>
        <SSN>999999999</SSN>
    </StateSeparationRequest>
</StateSeparationRequestCollection>
```

I am trying to find duplicate element Values at StateRequestRecordGUID, and if duplicates are found, remove them from the document.

Here is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlreader);
XNamespace ns = "https://uidataexchange.org/schemas";

var duplicates = (from req in doc.Descendants(ns + "StateSeparationRequest")
                  group req by req.Descendants(ns + "StateRequestRecordGUID").First().Value
                  into g
                  where g.Count() > 1
                  select g.Skip(1)).SelectMany(elements => elements);
foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
{
    duplicate.Remove();
}

var node = doc.Descendants(ns + "EmployerTPASeparationRequest");
var node2 = node.ElementAt(i);
string _StateRequestRecordGUID = "";

foreach (var element in node2.Elements())
{ ...
```

This is what the output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StateSeparationRequestCollection xsi:schemaLocation="https://uidataexchange.org/schemas SeparationRequest.xsd" xmlns="https://uidataexchange.org/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <StateSeparationRequest>
    <StateRequestRecordGUID>30000000000000000000000000004000</StateRequestRecordGUID>
        <SSN>999999999</SSN>
    </StateSeparationRequest>
</StateSeparationRequestCollection>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem. Your code works correctly for me. Although I have no idea what the code starting with `var node` does, but it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Yup, works fine for me too. That's a nice use of grouping in linq-to-xml.

Comment: Does not work for me.  I am not sure what the deal is!

Comment: Oh and I have to give props to @jlew for the linq-to-xml routine.

Comment: I don't see where you save req afterwards, so if you expecting the file to be updated, you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var dups = doc.Descendants(ns + "StateSeparationRequest").GroupBy(e => e.Descendants(ns +"StateRequestRecordGUID").First().ToString());
//remove the duplicates
foreach (XElement ele in dups.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)))
    ele.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed on parent node that I didn't display in the xml files.  I needed to add a parent called EmployerTPASeparationRequest, then use that in the from statement.