# Removing duplicates in XML for linq and C#

Tags: .net, xml, linq, duplicates

First of all, I thank everyone for his or her patience with my questions.
I searched here
[Why doesn't this code find any duplicates within an xml element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064330/why-doesnt-this-code-find-any-duplicates-within-an-xml-element)
and
[remove a duplicate element(with specific value) from xml using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012101/remove-a-duplicate-elementwith-specific-value-from-xml-using-linq)
and am close, but not getting it.

I need to remove duplicate elements in the XML.  These elements may or may not exist

The XML snippet is as follows.  In need to remove the duplicate BuildNumber elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProductSessions FileID="{C7DCB747-AB3A-4222-B14B-F7A7994C212F}">
    <Session LicenceNumber="E2240A66AC64CB770000" SessionGuid="{20c5d49e-7442-4fd0-b612-23aa743f4bd9}" FK_FileId="{C7DCB747-AB3A-4222-B14B-F7A7994C212F}">
      <TimeOpened>2013/10/14 11:18:43</TimeOpened>
      <LicenseInfo Configuration="XYZ" Description="Company Standard Config+More" DongleID="-error-no-dongle-" LicenseKey="FLEXlm Server Licence" Licensed="Company  USA" FK_Sess  ionGuid="{20c5d49e-7442-4fd0-b612-23aa743f4bd9}" />
    <ProductVersion>Product 9.0.0 NTx86-64 (build 987)</ProductVersion>
      <BuildNumber>987</BuildNumber>
      <ProductArchitecture>NTx86-64</ProductArchitecture>
      <ProductVersion>9.0.0</ProductVersion>
      <SystemInfo OperativeSystem="Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise Edition (build 9200) 64-bit" User=" " FK_SessionGuid="{20c5d49e-7442-4fd0-b612-23aa743f4bd9}" />
      <ApplicationName>X</ApplicationName>
      <TimeClosed>2013/10/14 11:42:57</TimeClosed>
</Session>
<Session LicenceNumber="E2240A66AC64CB770000" SessionGuid="{5682f705-baa1-46c0-a5ca-    3c6d816c94cc}" FK_FileId="{C7DCB747-AB3A-4222-B14B-F7A7994C212F}">
      <TimeOpened>2013/10/14 11:55:23</TimeOpened>
      <LicenseInfo Configuration="XYZ" Description="Company Standard Config+More" DongleID="-error-no-dongle-" LicenseKey="FLEXlm Server Licence" Licensed="Company  USA" FK_SessionGuid="{5682f705-baa1-46c0-a5ca-3c6d816c94cc}" />
      <ProductVersion>Product 8.2.x NTx86-64 (build 123)</ProductVersion>
      <BuildNumber>123</BuildNumber>
      <BuildNumber>123</BuildNumber>
      <BuildNumber>123</BuildNumber>
      <ProductArchitecture>NTx86-64</ProductArchitecture>
      <ProductVersion>8.2.x</ProductVersion>
      <SystemInfo OperativeSystem="Microsoft Enterprise Edition (build 9200) 64-bit" User=" " FK_SessionGuid="{5682f705-baa1-46c0-a5ca-3c6d816c94cc}" />
      <ApplicationName>X</ApplicationName>
      <TimeClosed>2013/10/14 11:58:20</TimeClosed>
    </Session>
```

}

My code is as follows

```
// This gets the correct # of sessions
IEnumerable<XElement> childElements =
from element in XmlFile.Elements().Descendants("Session")
select element;
foreach (XElement el in childElements)
{
var dups = XmlFile.Descendants(el.n).GroupBy(e =>      e.Descendants("BuildNumber").First().ToString());
//remove the duplicates
foreach (XElement ele in dups.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)))
ele.Remove();
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var duplicates = xDoc.Root
                     .Elements("Session")
                     .SelectMany(s => s.Elements("BuildNumber")
                                       .GroupBy(b => (int)b)
                                       .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)))
                     .ToList();

foreach (var item in duplicates)
    item.Remove();
```

Or using `IEnumerable<XNode>.Remove()` extension method:

```
xDoc.Root.Elements("Session")
         .SelectMany(s => s.Elements("BuildNumber")
                           .GroupBy(b => (int)b)
                           .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))).Remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I appreciate it, seriously.  I had to absolutely get something done this AM

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlFile.Descendants("Session")
       .SelectMany(s => s.Elements("BuildNumber").Skip(1))
       .Remove();
```

This query selects all but first BuldNumber elements from each Session and removes them. Thus only first BuildNumber element will stay in each Session element.

Comment: This, of course, assumes that you only have a *single* BuildNumber for each session. If, however, multiple BuildNumbers are allowed as long as they have different values...

Comment: Hi - Thank you very much.  This is working in my console app I am using  for debugging.  I am trying to make it work now in SSIS and am hitting some issues for some reason.

Comment: @LeviCalhoun what kind of issues you have?

Comment: @BrunoBrant yes, sure. I wrote query which satisfies xml sample above - numbers are same, and all are numbers (no strings, or versions like `1.2.3.4`)

Comment: Thank you. I have it working in SSIS now too.  @ bruno - these are all the same build.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - I am working now.  The SSIS issue was on my end.  I updated to VS2013 over the weekend and it broke SSIS.  I had to go back and remove it, reinstall SQL 2012, install 2010 and then follow some instructions to install the MSI files.  I don't have enough reputation to mark this with a checkmark, or I would